# Can I update a user document whenever a user updates his authentication profile?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working with flutter and I have a AuthenticationProvider. Whenever my user signs in with his phone I update his profile as well. But my problem is that auth users can't be queried. So I read that I should keep a separate user collection. Now my question is, is it possible to update a user document in my user collection whenever a user updates his auth profile? I would like to do this with cloud functions but I noticed that there is only a create and delete? So how can I do this?

This is what I currently have

**Authentication Provider**

```
  Future<void> _verificationComplete(BuildContext context, AuthCredential authCredential, userInfo.UserInfo userInfo) async {

    AuthResult authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
    final userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
    userUpdateInfo.displayName = userInfo.name;
    userUpdateInfo.photoUrl = userInfo.photoUrl;
    await authResult.user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
    await authResult.user.reload();
    user = UserModel.fromFirebase(authResult.user);
    _status = AuthenticationStatus.authenticated;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

**Cloud function**

```
export const onUserCreated = functions.region('europe-west1').auth.user().onCreate(async user => {

    const privateUserData = {
        activeGroup: '',
        cloudMessagingToken: '',
    }

    const publicUserData = {
        name: '',
        photoUrl: '',
    }

    const promises = [];
    promises.push(firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('private').doc('data').set(privateUserData));
    promises.push(firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('public').doc('data').set(publicUserData));
    return await Promise.all(promises);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Cloud Functions trigger for when a user updates their Firebase Authentication profile. I'd highly recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for that, as it's much missed.

For now, the closest you can get is with a Cloud Function that you call directly from the application code. The two options there are:

1. Have your application code call the Firebase Authentication API first, then when that completes, have it call your custom Cloud Function to update the database too.
2. Have your application code call the Cloud Function immediately, and then have the Cloud Function [update both the user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) and the database.

I somehow often do the first one, but see more developers take the second approach. I think their approach is probable simpler, but I just haven't gotten around to it yet. :)

Comment: Two years later, is this still the case? Is there a Cloud Functions trigger for when a user updates their Firebase Authentication profile?

Comment: The situation is still the same as when I wrote this answer.